# How to design a control when you select any 3 of 4 parameters to get the remaining one

Tags: usability, controls, multi-selection

I am thinking from the UX perspective about implementing a control where there are four parameters (see example below). The user can select the values for any three of them to get the value of the fourth (parameters are related).

#### Example

The 4 parameters are **E** (energy), **V** (voltage), **I** (current), **t**(time). When I select any 3 out of the 4 - the last one is obtained from the equation - E = V x I x t (energy = voltage x current x time).

Comment: The simplest solutions is 4 inputs with good written logic?

Comment: The problem is that 4th input becomes an output when I have the rest 3 inputs.

Comment: If you have 1,2,3  (4 automatic), when you have 2,3,4 (1 automatic), when you have 3,4,1(2 automatic) - You have 24 combinations - so i think the inputs should be identical - if there is one unknown in the equation - it doesn't matter which input.

Comment: I have found a very similar question discussed here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/entering-any-two-of-four-inter-dependent-values - I do not like the solutions there. Has to be a more intuitive way?

Comment: A similar question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/60022/36883. It's about a calculator and seems almost the same.

Comment: Substitute your parameters with inputs in that very equation: energy = voltage x current x time. So the user sees the exact formula and your logic auto calculates the missing value and highlights the input with a different background (I prefer a blue shade, it somehow strikes as "info" in my head. Maybe from using Twitter bootstrap in past) or even pop out the output slightly and make it bigger (and the font size) to tell that it is the one that's calculated. Cheers

Comment: There are plenty of inspirations that you can take from Wolfram Alpha, such as the Ohm's Law Calculator: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ohm%27s+law+calculator&lk=3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[vkrouglov](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/133074/vkrouglov) You can try this approach:

By offloading the work upfront, ask for the missing details (i.e output)
[image]

Comment: Yes, it's seem optimized & easy - also You can "pull" values from dropdown to buttons / tabs.